# При маппинге объекта через RowMapper, как правильно получать ссылки на другие объекты?

Tags: java, mapping, jdbctemplate

Пытаюсь разобраться с JDBC Template

Дано - класс `User` и класс `Passport`.
В классе `User` есть поле с типом `Passport`

Делаю запрос к БД, получаю `resultSet`, содержащий данные `user`'a, а также `id`'шник на passport

Соответственно, хочу `resultSet` преобразовать в объект `User`. Использую класс-маппер

```java
public class UserMapper implements RowMapper<User> {

    @Override
    public User mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int rowNum) throws SQLException {

        return new User(resultSet.getInt("id"),
                resultSet.getString("name"),
                resultSet.getString("surname"),
                //тут надо получить паспорт         
        );
    }
}
```

Вопрос - как мне заполнить поле паспорта?

Вижу пока два варианта:

1. В `User` хранить не ссылку на `Passport`, а `int passport_id`.
   И в случае, когда надо будет получить паспорт, писать:

```java
Passport pass = passportDAO.getPassport(user.gerPassportID());
```

Получается ленивая загрузка.

2. Либо же в `UserMapper` использовать `PassportDAO` и сразу его подтягивать

```java
public class UserMapper implements RowMapper<User> {

    private final PassportDAO passportDAO;

    public UserMapper(PassportDAO passportDAO) {
        this.passportDAO = passportDAO;
    }

    @Override
    public User mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int rowNum) throws SQLException {

        return new User(resultSet.getInt("id"),
                resultSet.getString("name"),
                resultSet.getString("surname"),
                passportDAO.getPassport(resultSet.getInt("passport_id")

        );
    }
}
```

Получается жадная загрузка.

Скажите, я правильно рассуждаю, что нужно так делать? Реальных проектов не видел, в уроках тоже.

Comment: С точки зрения феншуя первый вариант предпочтительнее - сервисный/бизнес слой определяет, каким образом собирать объект. А вот когда вам надо будет формировать список юзеров, то появится серьёзное проседание в производительности. И придётся выбирать что делать - сохранять стандартные круды, либо доставать всё сразу одним запросом.